# SQL: One to Many, where one of the Many relations has two specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, one-to-many

I want to get all records from table A, where 'some_value' and 'some_other_value' is present in two different columns (for the same record) in table B - But for each record in table A that has a record in table B with a specific value, I also want all the other records from table B that belongs to the record in table A.

An example:
I have a users table (Table A) and a images table (table B). I want all users and all their images, where at least one of the images is called "some-name.png" and that image type is "profile pictue".

The following will not give me all other images for users that has this specific picture

```
SELECT * 
FROM users  
JOIN images
ON users.id = images.user_id
WHERE images.name = 'some-name.png' 
   AND images.type = 'profile picture'
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: This will give you all users who have who have atleast one "some-name.png". Now join these users with images to get all their images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN images i ON u.id = i.user_id AND i.name = 'some-name.png' AND i.type = 'profile picture'
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM   users u
       JOIN images i
         ON u.id = i.user_id
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT user_id
               FROM   images i1
               WHERE  u.id = i1.user_id
                      AND i1.name = 'some-name.png'
                      AND i1.type = 'profile picture')
       AND i.type = 'profile picture' ;
```

sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3d7f/11)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from images I
JOIN (
select distinct U.* from users U
join images SI
on U.id = SI.user_id
where SI.name = 'some-name.png'
and SI.type = 'Prpfile picture') as SIU
ON SIU.id = I.user_id
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71b25d/5)